# Perl: Why can I call subroutine A recursively, but I can't call A from B, which is called from an earlier A?

Tags: perl, function, syntax

Try to "Play again" by answering Y when asked. Or am I just missing something completely obvious?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
sub calc() {
    $circ = 2 * $radius * 3.141592654;
    print "The circumference is $circ\nPlay again (Y/n)? ";
    $again = <STDIN>;
    if ($again eq "Y") {
        dialog();
    } else {print "Bye!\n"; 
    }
}

sub dialog {
    print "What's the radius of the circle you'd like the circumference of?\n> ";
    $radius = <STDIN>;
    if ($radius eq "\n") {
        print "That was just a blank line!\n";
        dialog();
    } elsif ($radius < 0) {
        print "That was negative! Let's assume radius is 0.\n";
        $radius = 0;
                calc();
    } else {calc();
    }
}
dialog();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't `chomp` your input from STDIN

```
chomp($again = <STDIN>);
```

Also, always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of each and EVERY perl script.

Finally, instead of doing recursion, a simple loop is sufficient.  The following is a cleaned up version of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (1) {
    print "What's the radius of the circle you'd like the circumference of?\n> ";
    chomp(my $radius = <STDIN>);

    if ($radius eq "") {
        print "That was just a blank line!\n";
        next;
    }

    if ($radius < 0) {
        print "That was negative! Let's assume radius is 0.\n";
        $radius = 0;
    }

    my $circ = 2 * $radius * 3.141592654;

    print "The circumference is $circ\nPlay again (Y/n)? ";

    chomp(my $again = <STDIN>);

    if ($again ne "Y") {
        print "Bye!\n";
        last;
    }   
}
```